# Storing Data in the correct way in Python

Tags: python, string, list, data-structures, while-loop

In Keywords.txt I have these words and their 'values':

```
alone,1

amazed,10

amazing,10

bad,1

best,10

better,7

excellent,10
```

These are some of the keywords and their 'values' that I need to store in a data structure, a list. Each line will be later used to access/extract the word and its 'value'.

The list I made in a while loop was:

```
line = KeywordFile.readline()

while line != '':

   line=KeywordFile.readline()
   line = line.rstrip()
```

And I tried to convert it to a list form by doing this:

```
   list=[line]
```

However, when I print the list, I get this:

```
['amazed,10']
['amazing,10']
['bad,1']
['best,10']
['better,7']
['excellent,10']
```

I don't think that I'll be able to extract my 'values' from the lists that easy if they are inside quotation marks.

I'm looking to get lists in this format:

```
['amazed',10]
['amazing',10]
['bad',1]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try `csv` module

Comment: `line.split(',')` will split the line on the comma.  A `dict` would be a good thing to store your data in.  It naturally falls into the key-value paradigm.  If you're creating the file (rather than getting it from something else), you could store the values in a pickle file and it would be easier to open/close.

Comment: Do you have to use a list or can you use a dictionary with the word (if there are no duplicates) being the key and the value being the number?

Answer (score 0):

You want to split the line into a list based on the string delimiter `','`.

```
list = line.split(',')
```

Then you want to convert the second value in each list into an int.

```
list[1] = int(list[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

put line `amazed,10` into sample.csv

```
    import csv

    with open('sample.csv') as csvfile:
        inputs = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in inputs:
            row = [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in row]  # convert numerical string to int which would remove quotes
            print(row)
```

output:

```
['amazed', 10]
```